# Where is the login code in joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

i am new to the joomla. I want to add webservice call after login, but i didn't get where the login code is or how can i add webservice call(Using username and password) after successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in joomla we do not usually alter core code.

You can do what you need, in the case you describe, by creating a plugin.

Here is the event that you need to create the plugin for:
http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterLogin

For information on how to develop plugins:
http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Plugin_Development

It is rather easy if you are familiar with php.